# ¿Como dejar corchetes vacios de una cadena transformada en array en javascript?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

tengo este código para pasar una cadena a un array

```
let str = 'Los desarrolladores de nik son [pepe] y [pepito]';
    let arr = str.split(' ');
    console.log(arr);
```

esto como resultado me da un array que contiene cada palabra, alguien sabe como hacer para que [pepe] y [pepito] queden dentro del array con los corchetes vacíos

que en vez de esto:

```
['Los', 'desarrolladores', 'de', 'plop', 'son', '[pepe]', 'y', '[pepito]']
```

quede esto:

```
['Los', 'desarrolladores', 'de', 'plop', 'son', '[]', 'y', '[]']
```

Comment: Usa `map` para recorrer ese array y dentro usa `includes` en un condicional para ver si contiene corchetes, y si los contiene los cambias por `[]`. Pruébalo y si no te sale puedes [edit] la pregunta con tus pruebas y te ayudamos a arreglarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los puedes hacer substituindo (con `string.replace` y una regex) los nombres en los corchetes por corchetes vacíos. Después el `array.split`. Algo como:

```js
const sentence = 'Los desarrolladores de nik son [pepe] y [pepito]';
const sentenceWithoutNames = sentence.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, '[]');
const sentenceWords = sentenceWithoutNames.split(' ');

console.log(sentenceWords);
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero debes evitar responder cuando el OP aún no ha probado nada (de ahí mi comentario, para que al menos hubiera probado de hacerlo por su cuenta, pues ni lo ha probado)